# I cant sculpt on mac

Tags: sculpting

My computer will not let me sculpt on 2.83 or 2.91. I really need help, I cant find a solution. When I click and drag nothing happens, I just get weird geometry, like in this image. [image]

Comment: Looks like the cube only has 3x3x3 =27 vertices. You should be able to drag them around but you can't expect a smooth high-poly sculpture from this. Do a remesh or add subdivisions.

Answer (score 2):

you are actually sculpting it 1)But your model has very low faces and verts,you should subdivide your mesh to get more details.2)you should use direct option from splash screen of sculpting layout because it has already subdivide mesh.have a look at this picture.this is what happens at low poly like you - [image]

And this is high poly mesh and subdivided:-
[image]